# 4 pieces into a big slitherlink

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

Arrange the 4 pieces into a big slitherlink.
To help you arrange it, First find the solvable small slitherlink then put it in the bottom-left position.

1st piece
[image]

2nd piece

[image]
3rd piece

[image]
4th piece

[image]

Comment: This is uniquely solvable, right?

Comment: @Wen1now yes uniquely solvable

Comment: @Wen1now the smaller slit is also uniquely solvable

Comment: So, none of these is individually solvable, or is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big slitherlink looks like this:

> [image]

Solve path:

> The first piece can not be on the bottom because a link has to leave to the bottom between the 2 and the 1. The second piece can not be on the right because either the 3s in the top right or the 3 in the bottom right will cause a contradiction. Next I tried the pieces 1, 3 and 4 in the top left (this would force the second piece into the bottom left) and found contradictions. This leaves the second piece in the top left and the first piece in the top right. The fourth piece can not be to the right of the third piece because the 3s there yield a contradiction. This leaves us with the order 2-1-4-3. The resulting big slitherlink can be solved fairly straightforward.

Comment: Bravo!
I was trying to solve each individual ones. Couldn't get much far.

Comment: How about the smaller slither?

Answer (score 2):

solution for  the smaller slither (4th piece)

> [image]

Comment: Perfect solve. +1